# Sorting bar charts in D3

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, bar-chart

I created a bar chart in D3 and I'm trying to sort the bars in a bar chart in ascending order on clicking, and on descending on clicking again. I added in the necessary code for sorting at the end of the code snippet but nothing happens on clicking (the bars don't sort). Not sure what I'm missing here, any help would be appreciated!

```
    <script>

    var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .tickFormat(formatPercent);

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
      })

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.call(tip);

    d3.tsv("data/bar-graph-tooltips.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
      x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Frequency");

      svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
          .on("click", function() {sortBars();});

          //Define sort order flag
        var sortOrder = false;

        //Define sort function
        var sortBars = function() {

            //Flip value of sortOrder
            sortOrder = !sortOrder;

            svg.selectAll("rect")
               .sort(function(a, b) {
                    if (sortOrder) {
                        return d3.ascending(a, b);
                    } else {
                        return d3.descending(a, b);
                    }
                })
               .transition()
               .delay(function(d, i) {
                   return i * 50;
               })
               .duration(1000)
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i);
               });

        };          
    });


    function type(d) {
      d.frequency = +d.frequency;
      return d;
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the values that need to be sorted in the `a, b`, here:

```
.sort(function(a, b) {
                if (sortOrder) {
                    return d3.ascending(a, b);
                } else {
                    return d3.descending(a, b);
                }
```

Something like: `a.value, b.value` but that depends on how your tsv is structured

Comment: It looks like @user3919759 is using [Scott Murray's example to sort bars](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch10.html#_click_to_sort). I'd recommend to look at his [working example](http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920026938/chapter_10/10_delay.html), and then add your additional features one by one.

Comment: yes, it is indeed that, I recognised it because I followed those tutorials myself :) And yes in the working example after the a and b there's a .value or .key to sort them by value or key

Comment: Yes it's the a.value and b.value that I'm missing since my data file has more than one column. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: yes, basically you were telling d3 to order your data but you weren't specifying which data to order. adding .whatever tells d3 to access that and order it